# how to obtain a value from a multidimensional array inside an object using a variable as index

Tags: php, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, methods

I'm trying to switch from procedural php to OOP php and i am quite new in this.

i created a class and i am trying to make a method but it dosn't work and i am quite sure it is a syntax issue.

here's the code:

```
    class abcd {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public $c;
    public $d;

    function rule(){
    $the_key = array_search($this->a, array_column($this->b, 'X'));
    if(is_null($this->b[$the_key]['Y']) && $this->c == 0){
    $output = $this->a . " some text here.";}
else {$output = null;}
    return $output;
    }
    }
```

I suspect the problem is with this expression because i tested and it doesn't return anything:

```
$this->b[$the_key]['Y']
```

if i set `$output` to `$the_key` in the else statement i get and integer. if i set it to `var_dump($this->b[$the_key]['Y'])` i get `NULL` while i should get a string

Comment: We would probably need to see what `$a`,`$b` and `$c` are.

Comment: You forgot semicolon `;` after variables

Comment: @Rishi i have them in my code

Comment: @AbraCadaver $a is a string, $b is an array, $c is an integer, $d is string

Comment: Like actual data that is being used.

Comment: Is b a multidimensional array or an array of objects?

Comment: @JoseRodrigues it has 2 dimensions. The first dimension has numeric keys the second one has letters a keys

Comment: Is this line complete `($this->a, array_column($this->b, 'X'));`. I understand what array_column does but what does (string,array) do.

Comment: @JoseRodrigues the result of the if is supposed to be a string that will be echoed later on

Comment: I get the rest, just this line `$the_key = ($this->a, array_column($this->b, 'X'));`.  What is `$the_key` suppose to be.  You use `array_column()` to get an array and you say `$this->a` is suppose to equal a string, then what does `$the_key = (stringA,array)` mean. (It could be that i dont know this opporation/function)

Comment: @JoseRodrigues it is array_search before (. i just modified the code...

Comment: You havent stated any kind of error, but If your getting an `variable undefined error` its because you have not defined $output if your `if` statement is `false`.  Now if your just not getting the value you want then try using `is_empty

Comment: @JoseRodrigues there is no error because I have an else that sets $output to null. Also === doesn't change much

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. The problem was that is $c was not an integer but an array.